# DHMS function returning 00:00 for hours and minutes

Tags: sas

DHMS function returning 00:00 for hours and minutes.

My date and time inputs are from an Oracle table and both are Number values. 
I’m trying to combine the two values to create a date time value. 
I can create an Auth_DT (DDMONYYYY) and Auth_Tm (HH:MM:SS). 
When I try to use DHMS to create an Auth Date Time the hours and minutes appear as 00:00,
but the seconds are correct.

I appreciate any help with the errors in my code.
Thank you in advance for any help.

```
data dates;
Auth_Date = 20120915; 
Auth_Time = 23324; 
run;

Proc SQL;
Create table mark as 
Select 
AUTH_DATE, 
input(put(AUTH_DATE,8.),yymmdd8.) as AUTH_DT format=Date9. ,
AUTH_TIME, 
input(put(AUTH_TIME,6.),hhmmss6.) as AUTH_TM format=TOD8. ,
Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),1,2),2.) as HR ,
Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),3,2),2.) as MIN , 
Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),5,2),2.) as SEC ,
DHMS((input(put(AUTH_DATE,8.),yymmdd8.))  
,HOUR(Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),1,2),2.)) 
,MINUTE(Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),3,2),2.)) 
,SECOND(Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),5,2),2.))) as Auth_DTTM Format = datetime20. 
From work.Dates;
Quit;
```

Auth_Date AUTH_DT      Auth_Time  AUTH_TM   HR  MIN SEC  Auth_DTTM
20120915     15SEP2012  23324        02:33:24   2   33  24   15SEP2012:00:00:24

Comment: I'm your example, `auth_date` is September 15, 2012.  But what actual time is `auth_time`?  Is that `02:33:24`?

Answer (score 4):

Without digging into your SQL code, this might do what you want:

```
data _null_;

   Auth_Date = 20120915; 
   Auth_Time = 23324; 

   /* Convert variables to SAS format */
   Auth_Date_SAS = input(put(Auth_Date,z8.),yymmdd8.);
   Auth_Time_SAS = input(put(Auth_Time,z6.),hhmmss6.);

   /* Build timestamp */
   Auth_Date_SAS_Timestamp = DHMS(Auth_Date_SAS,0,0,Auth_Time_SAS);

   put Auth_Date_SAS_Timestamp= datetime.;
run;
```

Basically, you need to convert your two variables into SAS format.  The "trick" is to just specifiy the time value as the last parameter to the `DHMS` function.  [See the last example in the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1b9d1kbo0czoxn1ouj1kcxwqzn1.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Bob's answer is the correct way to go about this, IMO.  To answer specifically why your solution was wrong, this is using the wrong argument for the HOUR function:

```
HOUR(Input(Substr( put(Auth_Time,z6.),1,2),2.))
```

That gives you, for 2:33:24,

```
HOUR(INPUT(SUBSTR('023324',1,2),2.))
```

so `HOUR(INPUT('02',2.))` or, finally, `HOUR(2)`;

HOUR does not, however, take an argument of 'integer number of hours'.  It *returns* an integer number of hours, from an argument of `time` (which is an integer number of seconds) or `datetime` (an integer number of seconds since 1/1/1960 00:00:00).

So if you were to do it this way (and again, Bob's solution is much simpler, since SAS stores time values as an integer number of seconds, and DHMS can take any number of seconds, even insanely large ones), you either need to remove the HOUR function, so

```
DHMS(<date part>,input(substr(put(auth_time,z6.),1,2),2.),
     input(substr(put(auth_time,z6.),3,2),2.),
     input(substr(put(auth_time,z6.),5,2),2.)));
```

Or use the complete time argument (ie, exactly what you store in AUTH_TM) and the HOUR/MINUTE/SECOND functions, ie

```
HOUR(input(put(AUTH_TIME,6.),hhmmss6.))
```

etc.